# Create custom Google Actions and call in French

Tags: api, google-api, google-home

I have just received my Google Home in France and setup in French language.
I tried to create a custom Action thanks the Api.ai website and Google Action Console but impossible to call my action in French.

It worked great when I set my Google Home to English(USA) language but not in French...

Do we have something special to set or to tell for work in French language ?

Thank you for your help there.

Answer (score 0):

Actions on Google do not support french yet.

Comment: No date expected ? :(